# Traveling to UK and have laptop gift for partner. Will I have to pay any import taxes?

Tags: usa, uk, customs-and-immigration, duty-free, import-taxes

I am traveling to the UK from the US.

Just wondering if I can take a laptop for my partner as a gift without having to declare it. I will have my own laptop in my backpack.

The gift will not be boxed. I will take it unboxed.

For anyone interested, it is a Razer Blade 15" valued at $1399 USD.

Comment: Strictly, yes, you should declare it. However, a traveller carrying a laptop computer is so commonplace that it won't attract any attention. Should Customs take an interest you risk a fine and/or confiscation of you haven't declared it.

Comment: @Arthur'sPass It would pretty much be two laptops in my backpack. Not in its original packaging.

Answer (score 8):

As HMG's [page on the subject](https://www.gov.uk/duty-free-goods/arrivals-from-outside-the-eu) says:

> Your duty-free allowance means you can bring in a certain amount of goods for your own use from outside the European Union (EU) without paying duty or tax.  When you’re bringing in goods you must:
>
> transport them yourself
> use them yourself or give them away as a gift

So these are the rules that cover bringing in gifts for UK residents.  After discussing alcohol and tobacco allowances, it goes on to say that

> You can bring in other goods worth up to £390 [...]
> If a single item’s worth more than your allowance you pay any duty or tax on its full value, not just the value above the allowance.

It goes on to note that you must

> Declare any goods over your allowance. Your goods could be seized if you do not declare them

You don't say what this "Razer Blade" is worth, but if it's more than £390 you should declare it, preferably with documentation as to the purchase value, and be prepared to pay duty on it.

Comment: "Starting from $1,599.99" (USD). That's probably a bit over the duty free allowance. I can't imagine any sale price that would bring it in range. That said, nobody looks twice at a laptop unless it's in its original box. Or perhaps you have a stack of them.

Comment: @MichaelHampton Not in original packaging. I will just have my own (MacBook) and then the gift in my backpack. I imagine I can just say they are both mine for personal use...

Comment: @Bryan We can't really advise you to break the rules, but we can say it's very unlikely you would be caught in this scenario. Having two laptops isn't all that unusual either.